# "Back to Top" button visibile only when the window is scroll (but with mobile doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, mobile

i'm trying to make a BTT (Back to Top): it's too easy, when the user scroll the entire window (viewport) appear the BTT on the bottom side of content (for example in web-site near the footer). So if the height's content is less than height's window the BTT is hidden.

The problem is that my code doesn't work on mobile (chrome, safari, firefox), while with desktop browser but with the resize window i don't have problems (eccept with chrome). I don't understand what is the problem...:

```
if($('body,html').scrollTop()< $(window).height()){
 $('#btt').css('display','none');
}

$('#btt').click(function(){
 $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0},400);
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($('body,html').scrollTop()< $(window).height()){
     $('#btt').css('display','none');
    }
     else{
        $('#btt').css('display','block');
    }
```

This CSS:

```
    #btt {
        background: #a0a0a0 none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border: 1px solid #404040;
        border-radius: 10px;    
        float: right;
        height: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 90px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #spanbtt {
        align-items: center;
        color: #000;
        display: flex;
        font-size: 15px;
        height: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #bttspanid {    
        font-size: 15px;    
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

And this HTML:

```
<div id="btt">
    <div id="spanbtt">Torna su <span id="bttspanid" class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span></div>
</div>
```

This is jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3z6yka72/

I tried also to replace  `$(window).height()` with `window.outerHeight` but i have however problems (with mobile browser the BTT is visible, but it is visible also if the height content is less than height window, while with desktop chrome the BTT is hidden)...

I hope that you can help me and sorry for my english.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a var for the height of the window so it is stored.

here is an updated fiddle for you.

```
$('#btt').click(function() {
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 400);
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowH = $(window).height();
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < windowH) {
    $('#btt').removeClass('show');
  } else {
    $('#btt').addClass('show');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3z6yka72/1/

Hope it helps.

Comment: hmm... i think that is not important stored the height of window... i think that my problem it was "$('body,html').scrollTop()" however thanks a lot